# How to rework a commit that has already been merged in an another branch

Tags: git

I have this situation

```
master    A--B--C
                 \
fix-15            D
                   \
other1        ...--(merged)--E
```

I missed something while working on `D` and I need to fix it on the same commit because I already sent a github pull request and the project owner wants a single commit per pull request. If `D` had not been merged in `other1` I could `reset` and `commit` again and then `push -f` my changes. But because of `other1`, `git reset` does not *uncommit* `D`.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what is a PR?

Comment: a github Pull Request. I edited my question to make this clearer.

Comment: Are you familiar with the majestic interactive rebase feature?

Comment: I don't think so. I mean I know `rebase -i` exists but I'd not know how to use it to solve my problem.

Comment: what branch did you send your PR to? Is that the place you want to send your updated code? If `other1` has merged the pull requests, that's it, you're done. Unless the "owner" of `other1` wants to go back in time (-f) you won't be able to do what you want how you want.

Comment: The PR is for `fix-15`.

Comment: @TimCastelijns: I took some time to lean how to use `rebase -i`. Wow.

Comment: @Sylvain excellent :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to *change* commit D, you'll have to make a replacement commit E, and probably a new pull request. If the project owner requires one-commit pull requests, you can amend your commit D, which will require you to replace *other1* brand with a completely new one, which can create problems for people who have already pulled it, if they are any.

First of all, let me mark a few more commits on you graph:

```
master    A--B--C
                 \
fix-15            D
                   \
other1         X -- Y (merge) -- E
```

So, what you can do:

```
git branch other1_copy other1 # make a copy
git checkout other1
git reset --hard X # get to the state before merge
git checkout fix-15
# do your changes
git commit --amend # make commit D'
git checkout other1
git merge fix-15 # make a replacement merge commit Y'
git checkout other1_copy
git rebase --onto other1 Y # rebase your changes in 'other1' onto Y'
git checkout other1
git merge other1_copy # now you have 'other1' as E'
git branch -d other1_copy # delete the temporary branch
```

This is what it will look like at the end

```
master    A--B--C
                 \
fix-15            D'
                   \
other1         X -- Y' (merge) -- E'
```

Even though this does what you asked for, it is a bit complex and it's quite possible they are ways of solving your problem without messing with your branches like this. One of them is adding another commit to *fix-15*, and merging it to *other1* via normal merge:

```
master    A--B--C
                 \
fix-15            D ------ F
                   \        \
other1         X -- Y -- E -- G
```

Then, if you have a branch tracking your upstream, you can create a one-commit pull request like this:

```
git fetch upstream # let's call your upstream remote `upstream`
git checkout -b pull-branch upstream/master
    # ^ you'll be using this to create a pull request
git merge --squash other1 && git commit
    # ^ creates a squashed commit will all the changes from `other1`
# now create a pull request from this branch
```

Comment: Sometimes you can use @{upstream} and not need to know the upstream remote name.  very git version dependent..  Has to be 1.7.1p2 or later...